# Argument type '"in"' not assignable to 'WhereFilterOp'

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I need to filter documents from a collection based on an array from a document in another collection. The two collections are **"parentAccounts" and "accounts"**.

For the given accounts

> account.accountId = '1'
>
> account.accountId = '2'
>
> account.accountId = '3'

I want to get just those who's ID is listed in an array of the parentAccount like:

> parentAccount.subAccountIds ['1', '3']

This is the query I *thought* I needed to use:

```js
accounts$ = afs.collection<MyAccount>('accounts', ref => ref
   .where('accountId', 'in', 
      this.parentAccount.subAccountIds) // previously loaded parentAccount.subAccountIds
   .orderBy('accountName'))
   .valueChanges()
```

But I cannot use '**in**' for the **WhereFilterOp**.

Comment: Based on your requirement, the [in operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) is the one you should use. Can you share the full error message you get when running this query? I tested a similar query with an `orderBy` filtering without issue. Also, what versions of Firestore and AngularFire are you using in your project?

Comment: It's not a runtime error but a compile time error: Argument type '"in"' not assignable to 'WhereFilterOp'. Basically that argument is not available. So I think I am trying to design it incorrectly. How do I check for a value on a document to see if it is in an array of values?

Comment: On my project I didn't receive any compilation errors from the query, even when replicating it with the collections you described. Since you need to filter documents if they contain a value that is present in an array then the `in` operator should be the proper solution. Can you post your full component where you are running this query? Also, which version of AngularFire are you using? [This issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2278) from the repo has your exact error, and it's related to using an outdated version.

Answer (score 0):

you should use
`'<' | '<=' | '==' | '>=' | '>' | 'array-contains'`